# Relevant months between start and finish dates-Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm using python/Pandas and analyzing raw data which have below kind of columns A to C.
What I'd like to do is to add new column D which shows relevant months between start and finish dates using Pandas.
It seems that data type of  start/finish dates are series and would you advise how can I get this results? I tried to use datetime module but it's not work well and can't identify the reason.

[image].

In text:

```
print (df)

  Participants       Start      Finish                 Month
1                                                           
2          AAA  2021-03-01  2021-05-30                 3,4,5
3          BBB  2021-03-01  2021-03-31                     3
4          CCC  2021-05-01  2021-07-31                 5,6,7
5          DDD  2021-04-01  2021-12-31  4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
```

Answer (score 1):

Use custom lambda function with [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html), converting values to strings and join together:

```
f=lambda x: ','.join(str(y.month) for y in pd.date_range(x['Start'],x['Finish'], freq='MS'))
df['Month'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print (df)
  Participants       Start      Finish                 Month
1                                                           
2          AAA  2021-03-01  2021-05-30                 3,4,5
3          BBB  2021-03-01  2021-03-31                     3
4          CCC  2021-05-01  2021-07-31                 5,6,7
5          DDD  2021-04-01  2021-12-31  4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
```